# Does this bibliography style citation have a specific name?

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

Does someone know if this bibliography style citation has a specific name?

Or is it a particular style?

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like the `alphabetic` style.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks.